# Spring struts and forms

Tags: spring, forms, struts

I need to integrate struts with spring for a project.

I read the doc to ingrate struts and it's ok for classic beans but I have a problem for my forms.

I have a form like this in my struts-config.xml:

```
  <form-beans>
<form-bean name="creationForm" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorActionForm" >

  <form-property name="libelle" type="java.lang.String" />
  <form-property name="quantite" type="java.lang.String" />
  <form-property name="prix" type="java.lang.String" initial="10" />

</form-bean>
```

But it's strange for me to have a "type" in struts-config because it's spring which manages beans.

I don't found anything in the doc to manage forms by spring and the attribute "type" is mandatory for form in struts-config.

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how it is that you had chosen to go about integrating the two frameworks but from experience I can tell you that it works.

for example my struts-config.xml has the following:

```
<struts-config>
    <!-- ================== Form Beans ================ -->
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="UploadForm" type="com.foo.bar.forms.UploadForm" />
    </form-beans>
    <!-- ================== Action Mapping Definitions ================ -->
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/pages/UploadFiles" name="UploadForm"
            type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy" scope="request"
            input="/pages/ImportFiles.jsp">
            <forward name="success" path="/pages/SwitchView.do" />
        </action>
    <!-- ================================ Plugins ============================== -->
    <plug-in className="org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn">
        <set-property property="contextConfigLocation"
            value="/WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" />
    </plug-in>
</struts-config>
```

my action-servlet.xml file contains the following bean definition:

`<bean name="/pages/UploadFiles" class="com.foo.bar.actions.UploadFilesAction" />`

This way Struts-1 retains control of the MVC but Spring "manages" the whole application.

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**

your web.xml should alos have the following:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**EDIT 2:**

> Hmm, in your struts-config, you set
>   the type for your form
>   (com.foo.bar.forms.UploadForm) like
>   me.
>
> My code work but it's strange struts
>   manage form beans and spring manage
>   other beans.

I don't think it is strange at all...

> Concretely, I would like to know if
>   it's possible to do that

Yes

add the bean:

```
<bean name="CaseUpdateForm" class="com.foo.bar.forms.CaseUpdateForm" >
```

and convert the bean above to:

```
<bean name="/pages/UploadFiles" class="com.foo.bar.actions.UploadFilesAction">
   <property name="updateForm" ref="UpdateForm" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, in your struts-config, you set the type for your form (com.foo.bar.forms.UploadForm) like me.

My code work but it's strange struts manage form beans and spring manage other beans.

Concretely, I would like to know if it's possible to do that (I use your example) :

struts-config:

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="UploadForm" />
</form-beans>
```

action-servlet:

```
 <bean name="UploadForm" class="com.foo.bar.forms.UploadForm" >
  </bean>
```